# How to remove main page title "Create New Customer Account" from registration page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

I am needing to remove the main page title "Create New Customer Account" from the registration page.

I see everywhere that I need to add the line below somewhere but where?

`<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />`

Essentially I'd like to remove the following div from the page.

```
    <h1 class="page-title">
        <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper">Create New Customer Account</span>    </h1>
    </div>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove page title from layout file i.e `customer_account_create.xml`

**Theme level:**

create

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{my-theme}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**Module level:**

create:

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override layout file in your custom theme with below code

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```